# methods that are returning different return types

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, dynamic-linq

I have below methods and they are returning different entities in addition to that the input parameters going to these methods all are same and I am using those ones in where condition

```
   public IQueryable<LibraryEnvironment> EnvironmentFields(string spaceFunction, string category, string source)
    {
        return _dbContext.LibraryEnvironment.Where(s => s.SpaceFunction == spaceFunction
                                                                && s.Category == category &&
                                                                 s.EnvironmentSource.Name == source);
    }

    public IQueryable<LibraryEquipment> EquipmentFileds(string spaceFunction, string category, string source)
    {
        return _dbContext.LibraryEquipment.Where(s => s.SpaceFunction == spaceFunction
                                                              && s.Category == category &&
                                                               s.EquipmentSource.Name == source);
    }

    public IQueryable<LibraryLighting> LightingFields(string spaceFunction, string category, string source)
    {
        return _dbContext.LibraryLighting.Where(s => s.SpaceFunction == spaceFunction
                                                             && s.Category == category &&
                                                              s.LightingSource.Name == source);
    }
```

there are other methods similar to this kind as well

I am looking for a way to create the common generic method among all these methods but with a different return type and could not be able to figure it out the way. I am using .Net core with EF core

if anyone suggest any ideas on this that would be very grateful to me, thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/), you can accept an `Expression<Func<TInput, TOutputProperty>>` to introduce a selector to allow you to choose `s.EnvironmentSource`, `s.EquipmentSource` or `s.LightningSource`

Comment: @ColinM could you please  provide us some sample code that would be very grateful

Comment: Does `s.EnvironmentSource`, `s.EquipmentSource` and `s.LightingSource` have a common base type or something? I see that all three of them have a `Name` property.

Comment: @Sweeper   yeah, they are all from single table and renamed it as per entities where  we are using them

Comment: Oh so they are all the same type? What type is it then?

Comment: @Sweeper  the type is an entity class that is having Id, name and other properties as well.

Comment: That it is a `IQueryable<T>` that you return is fixed, but not what the T is? If so, this might fall under Co- and Contravariance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravarianc | While it is very strictly not inheritance, it is designed to work pretty similar. But I never could remember wich variance was wich.

Comment: Could any one please suggest any ideas on this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Set<T>` method on `DbContext` to generically access sets. If you put all the relevant properties your filtering on into a base you can then constrain the generic parameter to that base type and still filter on all your properties.

So your classes would look something like this based on your original queries:

```
public class Entity
{
    public string SpaceFunction { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class LightingEquipment : Entity
{
    public LightingSource LightingSource { get; set; }
}

public class LightingSource
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And your method would like this, using a source selector:

```
public IQueryable<T> Fields<T>(string spaceFunction, string category, string source, Func<T, string> sourceSelector) where T : Entity
{
    return _dbContext.Set<T>().Where(s => s.SpaceFunction == spaceFunction
                              && s.Category == category &&
                              sourceSelector(s) == source);
}
```

And you would call this method like this:

```
public void Consumer()
{
    var queryable = Fields<LightingEquipment>("spaceFunction", "category", "source", x => x.LightingSource.Name);
}
```

[Docs for `Set<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-3.1)

Comment: thanks for suggestion, how can i call this method .

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going to find that your current design is the cleanest. Your code isn't completely "generic" since they pull from different tables and have different where clauses (e.g. `s.EnvironmentSource.Name == source` vs `s.LightingSource.Name == source`).

You *might* be able to combine *some* of the functionality by, for example, genericising the table access by type and combining the `s.Category == category` part of the filter, but you're going to have a mix of reflection (or switch statements) and generics that could be uglier than what you have now.

Comment: many thanks for suggestion, I am OK with switch statements either

Answer (score 2):

If you're only looking to have **one** method, perhaps you can get away with Generics, as @ColinM mentioned while checking the type to decide which block of code to execute.
Haven't tested it, and it could be the wrong approach. It depends a bit on where you're using it.

```
public T Fields<T>(string spaceFunction, string category, string source)
{
    Type tt = typeof(T);
    if(tt == typeof(IQueryable<LibraryEnvironment>))
        return _dbContext.LibraryEnvironment.Where(s => s.SpaceFunction == spaceFunction
                                                        && s.Category == category &&
                                                          s.EnvironmentSource.Name == source);
    if (tt == typeof(IQueryable<LibraryEquipment>))
        return _dbContext.LibraryEquipment.Where(s => s.SpaceFunction == spaceFunction
                                                      && s.Category == category &&
                                                        s.EquipmentSource.Name == source);
    if (tt == typeof(IQueryable<LibraryLighting>))
        return _dbContext.LibraryLighting.Where(s => s.SpaceFunction == spaceFunction
                                                      && s.Category == category &&
                                                      s.LightingSource.Name == source);
    return default;
}
```

You can then call the method specifying the return type:

```
Fields<IQueryable<LibraryEnvironment>>("a", "b", "c");
Fields<IQueryable<LibraryEquipment>>("a", "b", "c");
Fields<IQueryable<LibraryLighting>>("a", "b", "c");
```

Comment: thanks , but if you are passing entities right from here `Fields<IQueryable<LibraryEnvironment>>("a", "b", "c")` and in the method `Fields<T>` is it possible to remove that if condition .. or any other way

Comment: How is `Fields<IQueryable<LibraryEnvironment>>("a", "b", "c")` preferable to `EnvironmentFields("a", "b", "c")`?  Even if you genericized the queryable part, you'd still just have ` `Fields<LibraryEnvironment>("a", "b", "c")` which is not better than the original.

Comment: `EnvironmentFields` would be "hardcoded". I find it a tad better, but i totally get your point.